# friends relationships using mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have these two tables:

```
user{id,name,password....};
friends{id,user_id,user_id2,accept(bool)}
```

for instance say i wanted to fetch friends for the user_id=14 and the row accept has to be 1! how would I do the mysql query thanks :)

ps. when fethcing the queries it has to be a 2 to way thing, if user1 is friends with user2
also means that user2 is friends with user1, if you get what I mean! :))

Comment: Ping please clarify. If A and B are friends , there are two records in the friends table --> (0,A,B,true) ; (1,B,A,true)  if both have accepted friendship.                                         (0,A,B,false) ; (1,B,A,true) if only B has accepted friendship, etc .. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't mean to be deprecating, but this is very, very basic sql, and you could have easily found the answer through google or books. That being said, here is the answer.

```
SELECT * FROM friends WHERE (user_id=14 OR user_id2=14) AND accept=true;
```

Let me break it down for you, since you are using SQL and if you don't learn it you will be wasting a lot of time searching for answers.

```
SELECT * FROM friends
```

means get all rows from friends. The "*" is a replacement for column names and means "all columns". For instance, if you had

```
SELECT (id,user_id) FROM friends
```

The rows returned would only contain those columns.

Then comes the WHERE clause.

```
WHERE (user_id=14 OR user_id2=14) AND accept=true
```

means exactly how it looks: the rows you select should have at least one user_id equal to 14 and accept should be true. MySQL uses true, false, and null (if allowed) for booleans. Some other database, like MSSQL, which uses a "BIT" type rather than a boolean uses 1, 0, or null for true, false, and null respectively.

The OR clause is because, as you stated in your edit, this friendship can be "2 way".

So if you put it together,

```
SELECT * FROM friends WHERE (user_id=14 OR user_id2=14) AND accept=true;
```

Comment: I think this will give you duplicate results.

Comment: That really depends on how he is inserting his data. I can't really tell based on his question, but my assumption is that "if user1 is friending user2, then user_id is user1 and user_id2 is user2, but user2 can also friend user1 back in which case there would be a row in the database where user2 is user_id and user1 is user_id2." The architecture sucks to say the least, but I answered the question.

Comment: if the architecture sucks then why dnt you offer us a suggestion, im sure a lot of people will learn from this!!

Comment: On second thought, I think a join table is the only way to go. But rather than an id on the friends, you should just have user_id and user_id2 as foreign keys to the user table. This will handle duplicates. You will probably have to check before you insert that user_id and user_id2 does not equal user_id2 and user_id, respectively. I don't think MySql will do that for you.

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following.

```
select 
 f1.user_id2 
from 
 user u,friends f1 , friends f2
where
f1.user_id1 = 14,
f1.accept = 1,
f1.user_id2 = f2.user_id1,
f2.user_id2 = f1.user_id1,
f2.accept = 1
```

Thanks,
Rohan

Edit: Only makes sense joining user u table if you need details for the friends. Otherwise you can take the user u table out.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably not do that in two tables.  It makes more sense to me to have this be a many to many relationship between users.  The problem you have is that you are capping the number of 'friends' in the friends table.  That is unless you have the friends tables as a child of user.  I'll assume there is a foreign key in the friends table pointing to user.  I think you're part way there, but not sure why you have user_id2 as it doesn't make sense relationally.  In this case the query would be:

```
select *
from user
   inner join friends on friends.user_id = user.id
where friends.id = true
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you every row for user_id=14 that accepted a friend

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  friends
WHERE
  user_id = 14
  AND
  accept = TRUE
```